# getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when using Picasso Library

Tags: android, picasso

I am updating profile picture using Picasso library. I am getting below issue

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.adamas.selfiereporter:id/profile_picture" (7f100176) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f100176}
```

this is picasso object

```
 Picasso.with(getContext())
                                .load(profileImageUrl)
                                .placeholder(R.id.profile_picture)
                                .transform(new PicassoRoundedTransformation())
                                .fit()
                                .noFade()
                                .into(personImagee);
```

getting issue at

```
 .into(personImagee);
```

please someone help me

Comment: Problem here `.placeholder(R.id.profile_picture)`

Comment: Self explanatory  error message... An ID resource value `is not a Drawable (color or path)`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing id in a placeholder, You have to pass a drawable there.

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(profileImageUrl)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_picture)
       .transform(new PicassoRoundedTransformation())
       .fit()
       .noFade()
       .into(personImagee);
```

Comment: check now @Basha

Comment: you have to add a drawable with name profile_picture in your resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

put your **profile_picture.png** to drawble folders  then 
Change this line   `.placeholder(R.id.profile_picture)` to  `.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_picture)`